# Wrong timezone in XMLGregorian calendar

Tags: java, web-services, gregorian-calendar

I am using the below code to set a XMLGregorianCalendar field in webservice

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date dateOfBirth = null;
try {
    dateOfBirth = format.parse(adult.getDob_day() + "-" + adult.getDob_month() + "-"
                               + adult.getDob_year() + " 00:00:00");
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error while parsing dateOfBirth. Cause " + e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
}
passenger.setDateOfBirthField(convertToXMLCalendar(dateOfBirth));
```

The method convertToXMLCalendar is as below

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLCalendar(Date date) {

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = null;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    if (date != null) {
        try {
            calendar.setTime(date);
            xmlCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while converting to XMLGregorianCalendar. Cause " + e.getMessage());
    //      e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return xmlCalendar;
}
```

My server location timezone is +03:00. But in few random scenarios the timezone is being send as +04:00 in SOAP request.

```
<ns7:dateOfBirthField>1955-08-27T00:00:00.000+04:00</ns7:dateOfBirthField>
```

Due to this the service is receiving the date as one day lesser than actual date. If I send 03-06-2014 00:00:00 its reaching the service as 02-06-2014 11:00:00.

If I set the time as 12:00:00 instead of 00:00:00 will it fix the issue. But whats the reason for this timezone change?

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs when formatting code in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't specify a time zone, so it's using your local time zone. I would suggest:

- Not parsing a value at all. You've got the individual day, month and year - so use that directly with a calendar!
- Pass a `Calendar` to `convertToXMLCalendar` instead of a `date`... if you need to at all (see below)
- Specify the time zone of the calendar as UTC if you really want to... although fundamentally I'd expect a `dateOfBirth` value to be *just* a date, to be honest, e.g. `1955-08-27`. That way you're not specifying a time zone at all.

In fact, given that you've got the year/month/day, I'd just create an XMLGregorianCalendar directly from those values:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(adult.getDob_year(),
                             adult.getDob_month(),
                             adult.getDob_day(),
                             DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED); // No time zone
```

Then you're representing a `date` rather than a `dateTime`, which is what fits your data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that its not taking the local timezone. My timezone is +03:00 but in the request which I mentioned its going as +04:00. The weirdness is that its happening very rarely, say 1 in 1000 requests. So such requests are captured wrongly in the system.

Comment: @Dinal: are you sure that it's not the offset in your time zone *for that date*? Mist time zones vary over time... Again, just nit specifying a time zone would be better.

Comment: Month is a String here "MMM". Thats why I didn't go with that approach. As you suggested, I will try setting the offset like xmlCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)... Also there are certain other dateTime fields in the same webservice request which are being passed with correct timezone [convertToXMLCalendar(new Date())]. Only DOB field is causing the issue, maybe the DateFormat.parse is the issue maker.

Comment: @Dinal: Ick - in that case, *just* fix that. (Ideally, make `getDob_month` return an integer instead, but at least separate that part out from the rest. There's no need to format integers only to parse them again.) I suspect the reason dates of birth are throwing you off is that they can be in the relatively distant past - when your time zone may have had very different rules.

Comment: Thats a very valid reason. I too noticed that all the cases had  DOB in 50s or early 60s, but never thought that timezone would have had different rules at that time. I will do a field test of this fix and will mark this as the answer if everything goes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar does not specify the time zone. I believe, just by modifying the convertToXMLCalendar method, we can get rid of this problem

```
private static XMLGregorianCalendar convertToXMLCalendar(Date date) {

    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = null;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
         // You can set GMT time zone or Default or whatever 
     //TimeZone myzone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    TimeZone myzone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    calendar.getInstance(myzone);
    if (date != null) {
        try {
            calendar.setTime(date);
            xmlCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return xmlCalendar;
}
```